# Obtaining the index of a word between two columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nlp, multiple-columns, spacy-3

I am checking on which words the SpaCy Spanish lemmatizer works on using the .has_vector method. In the two columns of the datafame I have the output of the function that indicates which words can be lemmatized and in the other one the corresponding phrase.

I would like to know how I can extract all the words that have False output to correct them so that I can lemmatize.

So I created the function:

```
def lemmatizer(text):
doc = nlp(text)
return ' '.join([str(word.has_vector) for word in doc])
```

And applied it to the column sentences in the DataFrame

```
df["Vectors"] = df.reviews.apply(lemmatizer)
```

And put in another data frame as:

```
df2= pd.DataFrame(df[['Vectors', 'reviews']])
```

The output is

```
index             Vectors              reviews
  1     True True True False        'La pelicula es aburridora'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

```
import pandas
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
df = pandas.DataFrame({'reviews': ["aaabbbcccc some example words xxxxyyyz"]})
```

If you want to use [has_vector](https://spacy.io/api/token#has_vector):

```
def get_oov1(text):
    return [word.text for word in nlp(text) if not word.has_vector]
```

Alternatively you can use the [is_oov attribute](https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes):

```
def get_oov2(text):
    return [word.text for word in nlp(text) if word.is_oov]
```

Then as you already did:

```
df["oov_words1"] = df.reviews.apply(get_oov1)
df["oov_words2"] = df.reviews.apply(get_oov2)
```

Which will return:

```
>                                   reviews              oov_words1              oov_words2
  0  aaabbbcccc some example words xxxxyyyz  [aaabbbcccc, xxxxyyyz]  [aaabbbcccc, xxxxyyyz]
```

#### Note:

When working with both of these ways it is important to know that this is model dependent, and usually has no backbone in smaller models and will **always** return a default value!

That means when you run the exact same code but e.g. with `en_core_web_sm` you get this:

```
>                                  reviews oov_words1                                    oov_words2
  0  aaabbbcccc some example words xxxxyyyz         []  [aaabbbcccc, some, example, words, xxxxyyyz]
```

Which is because `has_vector` has a default value of `False` and is then not set by the model. `is_oov` has a default value of `True` and then is not by the model either. So with the `has_vector` model it wrongly shows all words as unknown and with `is_oov` it wrongly shows all as known.

Comment: Yes it works, but it does not show all the words that have a problem. There is no way to identify the word that returns False after applying the lemmatizer? For example using lambda function and filter?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, the words that are left over in the `oov_words1` and `oov_words2` columns in my example are the ones that return False. Does your real `lemmatizer()` method more than the one you wrote in your example does? You can use a lambda method but for how you currently use it you don't really need it and it is better (faster) to avoid lamdba in pandas apply when you can instead just use a self defined method that does the same.